# CvIPL definition

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am doing a project where I cannot use the opencv library. So I was trying to look at the source code and modify and use some of them as I need.

But I had a problem with the cvCreateData(..) function , When I go inside the function they use a structure 'CvIPL' for 'CvIPL.allocateData' but when I right click on it and try to go to definition, it says no definition is found.

I google with 'CvIPL' and I found it in the 'array.cpp' which states like this-

```
static struct
{
    Cv_iplCreateImageHeader  createHeader;
    Cv_iplAllocateImageData  allocateData;
    Cv_iplDeallocate  deallocate;
    Cv_iplCreateROI  createROI;
    Cv_iplCloneImage  cloneImage;
}
CvIPL;
```

Theproblem now is I don't know what is  Cv_iplCreateImageHeader,Cv_iplAllocateImageData... and cannot find any defination for them when I right click on them.

Can any one please tell me what is the type of Cv_iplCreateImageHeader,Cv_iplAllocateImageData... or where can I find some definations for tehm?

Answer (score 1):

If you still need this, here is the answer:

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2005. Right clicking and looking for symbol info works fine for me. But when in doubt (and I often am :), use grep! Using cygwin, I ran

```
cd ~/opencv
find . | xargs grep -l Cv_iplCreateImageHeader
```

One of the files listed is `./modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h`, which contains the lines

```
typedef IplImage* (CV_STDCALL* Cv_iplCreateImageHeader)
                            (int,int,int,char*,char*,int,int,int,int,int,
                            IplROI*,IplImage*,void*,IplTileInfo*);
typedef void (CV_STDCALL* Cv_iplAllocateImageData)(IplImage*,int,int);
typedef void (CV_STDCALL* Cv_iplDeallocate)(IplImage*,int);
typedef IplROI* (CV_STDCALL* Cv_iplCreateROI)(int,int,int,int,int);
typedef IplImage* (CV_STDCALL* Cv_iplCloneImage)(const IplImage*);
```

So basically, `CvIPL` is an abstract virtual class and `createHeader` and the other members are virtual functions with types `Cv_iplCreateImageHeader`, etc. It's just like C++ but written in C.